# Taylor series with two variables

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I need to find the Taylor series of $e^{{(x+y)}/{(1-x+y)}}$ around point $(0, 0)$.

I tried to replace $x+y = t$, and just got $1$. I think it's not quite right. How I can solve this problem?

$e^{{(x+y)}/{(1-x+y)}} = 1 + {(x+y)}/{(1-x+y)}$ - Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax for your questions for better readability, here is a helpful link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The last expression is not a Taylor series.